# Fetching the values from dynamically generated text boxes and input fields

Tags: javascript

Following is my code in which I am adding rows with text boxes and drop downs dynamically.

**Javascript:**

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                    break;

            case "select-one":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="load()">
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>

            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt[]" id="t1"/></TD>
            <TD>
                <SELECT name="country[]" id="t2">
                    <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
```

Now i am trying to fetch the values from fields added dynamically so that i can display it in table format . But i am not getting by which way i can do it . Please help.

Comment: I could be totally wrong on this but I think that the innerHTML is the problem as it isn't 'registering' the new controls (<select> etc) in the browser. You might have to use the DOM methods of creating the actual elements.

Comment: you mean user-entered values? upon what? a button click or server submit? what technology are you depending on? PHP? ASP?...

Comment: @Ayyash : I mean user entered values